# Can't connect/enable both ethernet connections

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager

I'm running Arch Linux with NetworkManager. I have an onboard Intel 1Gbe RJ-45 port, which is for my network and Internet. It is setup to automatically get an IP address from my router. The IP address for this is `192.168.0.173` with a netmask of `255.255.255.0`. The device name is `enp7s0`.

I also have a dual-port 10Gbe HP PCIe card. It is connected to my other machine with the same exact card using only 1 out of the two ports. I had configured this to use a static IP address of `10.0.0.1`. The machine on the other end is static IP address `10.0.0.2`. They both have a netmask of `255.255.0.0`. The device name for this is `enp4s0f0`. It's a P2P setup between two NAS servers if that matters.

The first time I set this up it was working fine. Both Ethernet connections were connecting simultaneously. After I rebooted my machine today it now only connects to 1 of the Ethernet connections. If I connect `enp4s0f0`, the other connection `enp7s0` gets disconnected, and vice-versa.

I'm not sure why all of a sudden it started doing this. Both of the NICs are on totally separate networks. I don't see any configuration files under `/etc/network/interfaces`, and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` is empty. The only configuration change I made was to setup a static IP address on the 10Gbe NIC (`enp4s0f0`). All the other settings were default.

Answer (score 1):

check the profiles you have with `nmcli connection`.

Usually, you would have (at least) two profiles, one for each interface. You would then also tie the profile to the right device via `connection.interface-name`. See the entire settings of the profile with `nmcli connection show "$PROFILE"` or `nmcli -o connection show "$PROFILE"`. Set the interface-name with `nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" connection.interface-name "$IFNAME"`.

Aside from `connection.interface-name` there are other properties that tie a profile to an interface. For example, you might set instead `ethernet.mac-address` property or the `match.*` properties (see `man nm-settings`), or you might not restrict this at all. It seems simplest to set `connection.interface-name`.

Then, ensure that both profiles are active (again, you see that in `nmcli connection` and `nmcli device` output. If not, activate the profiles with `nmcli connection up "$PROFILE"`.

> I don't see any configuration files under /etc/network/interfaces, and /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf is empty.

Check `nmcli -f all connection` to find the filename of the profile. You don't need to care about that very much, except, if the filename is under `/run`, it won't survive a reboot. In any case, it can be interesting to look at the files.